# matterJS remove all the external forces (including gravity)

Tags: matter.js

My need is to give a upward force each time, the height of the same ball, what should I achieve? , Now the problem is that each time the same upward force, the ball is not the same as the height of the ball, because there is gravity, I want to remove all the external forces (including gravity), and then give the ball an up Force

```
this.ball.isStatic = true;
            this.Matter.Body.applyForce(this.ball, this.ball.position, {
                x: this.addForceX,
                y: this.addForcey,
            });
            this.ball.isStatic = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Gravity can be removed by setting `engine.world.gravity.y = 0` after you create your engine (using `Matter.Engine.create()`). Then as long as you dont use `Matter.Body.applyForce()` anywhere else to add force to the object, it should only be effected by the force you added in that code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This will clear all forces of all bodies

`Engine._bodiesClearForces(this.world.bodies)`